# Change transperency of main screen on DrawerLayout menu open

Tags: android, android-drawer

I am using Drawer Layout on my application's home screen to provide some menu options. when drawer opens I want to add some gradient or some invisibility to background activity. How can I do that?
I have used below two methods but it wont work and visibility od main screen remains same

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(getDrawable(R.drawable.loading_top_bar), GravityCompat.START);
```

and

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor() Method
```

From both methods screen behind NavigationDrawer is clearly visible, I want to blur it so that it's visible but not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
_drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 255, 255));
```

you can create custom color with an opacity